# Stored Procedure to Return no of records for current minute and current date

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, count

Below is the structure of my table and indexes created.

I just want to create a stored procedure to insert record into this table and return no of records in the table for the current min and current day.

Below Stored procedure does the job. Please let me know if there is a better way of doing this.

```
CREATE table RCDC_THROTTLE
( 
  UUID varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  TRANSACTIONTIMESTAMP timestamp NOT NULL,
  TIMESTAMP timestamp NOT NULL,
  REQTYPE varchar2(20) NOT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX RCDC_THROTTLE_TIMESTAMP_IDX ON RCDC_THROTTLE(TIMESTAMP);
CREATE INDEX RCDC_THROTTLE_REQTYPE_IDX ON RCDC_THROTTLE(REQTYPE);

ALTER TABLE RCDC_THROTTLE
    ADD CONSTRAINT CK_RCDC_THROTTLE_REQTYPE CHECK (REQTYPE IN ('CONNECT','DISCONNECT'));
COMMIT;


create or replace PROCEDURE P_INSERT_RCDC_THROTTLE
(
  I_UUID IN VARCHAR2
, I_TRANSACTIONTIMESTAMP IN TIMESTAMP 
, I_TIMESTAMP IN TIMESTAMP 
, I_REQTYPE IN VARCHAR2 
, O_COUNTCURDAY OUT INT
, O_COUNTCURMIN OUT INT
) AS 
BEGIN

      INSERT INTO RCDC_THROTTLE(UUID, TRANSACTIONTIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMP,REQTYPE)
      VALUES (I_UUID,I_TRANSACTIONTIMESTAMP,I_TIMESTAMP,I_REQTYPE);
      select COUNT(*) INTO O_COUNTCURDAY from RCDC_THROTTLE where TIMESTAMP >= trunc(systimestamp);
      select COUNT(*) INTO O_COUNTCURMIN from RCDC_THROTTLE where TIMESTAMP > systimestamp - numtodsinterval(1,'MINUTE');
END;
```

Comment: TIMESTAMP is a reserved word and may not be used as an object (column) name.  Well, you could force it by jumping through some hoops, but that is such an atrociously bad idea I'm not going to explain those hoops.

Comment: @EdStevens It seems that is not the case [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bd7e9de1cb01574ba762adfa850b4bb2). That is not to say that using it is a good idea (and that it wouldn't be better to pick another name) but it is syntactically valid without using quoted identifiers.

Comment: @MT0 - Wow!  Not quite trusting db fiddle, I reproduced it with good old sqlplus.  When I tried other reserved words (DATE, NUMBER, TABLE) it errored out as expected. But it did accept TIMESTAMP as a column name.  For further discussion outside of the SO format, I've posted about it at https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4485549/keyword-timestamp-accepted-as-a-column-name/p1?new=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the table's column types in the signature and can perform both `COUNT`s in the same `SELECT` statement (so that you do not need to query the table twice):

```sql
create or replace PROCEDURE P_INSERT_RCDC_THROTTLE
(
  I_UUID                 IN RCDC_THROTTLE.UUID%TYPE
, I_TRANSACTIONTIMESTAMP IN RCDC_THROTTLE.TRANSACTIONTIMESTAMP%TYPE
, I_TIMESTAMP            IN RCDC_THROTTLE.TIMESTAMP%TYPE
, I_REQTYPE              IN RCDC_THROTTLE.REQTYPE%TYPE
, O_COUNTCURDAY          OUT INT
, O_COUNTCURMIN          OUT INT
) AS 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO RCDC_THROTTLE(
    UUID, TRANSACTIONTIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMP,REQTYPE
  ) VALUES (
    I_UUID,I_TRANSACTIONTIMESTAMP,I_TIMESTAMP,I_REQTYPE
  );

  SELECT COUNT(*),
         COUNT(CASE WHEN TIMESTAMP > SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1' MINUTE THEN 1 END)
  INTO   O_COUNTCURDAY,
         O_COUNTCURMIN
  FROM   RCDC_THROTTLE
  WHERE  TIMESTAMP >= trunc(systimestamp);
END;
/
```